# Handle multiple spring security context files based on property file's value

Tags: spring, properties, spring-security

I'm having problem with handling multiple security context files. Let me describe what I'm trying to do:

I have my existing application which is running perfectly with my current spring security configuration. I'm trying to introduce another security mechanism that handle application security in different way. But I want to keep our existing security config as a backup and want to handle which one to use from a property file.

Say I have two spring security context files:

----> applicationContext-security.xml

----> applicationContext-security-new.xml

And I have a property something like this:
spring.config.use.new.config=true

So if the property file is true it will use the new context file. If something goes wrong I will just change the property file and can use existing security mechanism.

Is that possible? Any information will be highly appreciated. Looking forward for anyone's answer :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you build your project with ?

If you use Maven you can just use the [properties plugin](http://haroon.sis.utoronto.ca/zarar/properties-maven-plugin/index.html) and have it replace your config definitions in your web.xml.

Your web.xml would look something like:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>${security.context.location}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Your pom.xml would have:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>my.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    <resources>
```

And your .properties file would have:

```
security.context.location = /somewhere/security-context-new.xml
```

or

```
security.context.location = /somewhere/security-context-old.xml
```